# Thunar custom action to open terminal as root

Tags: xubuntu, xfce, thunar, thunar-custom-actions

How to edit the custom action that would open a root Terminal in a given folder?

[Here](http://pclosmag.com/html/Issues/201308/page02.html) it says to use `gksu terminal`

[image]

[here](http://docs.xfce.org/xfce/thunar/custom-actions#opening_a_root_thunar) to add `gksu “xfce4-terminal –default-working-directory=%f”`

But they don't work in Xubuntu 12.04, Thunar 1.6.3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The good command is `gksu xfce4-terminal`

[image]